# Chunked Steam error in android HTTP post

Tags: java, php, android, http, post

I'm working on creating an android app that will pull down user data from a MySQL database stored on a web server. I've read a few tutorials on HTTP Post that allows me to connect to the database, which I got working. However, I am unable to process the data that gets sent from the php.

The error I receive is: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Chunked stream ended unexpectedly.

This is the code I have written:

```
String name = username.getText().toString();  //username is a TextView field
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);       
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user",name));
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(location);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }

    //Convert response to string
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();

        Log.i("log_tag", result);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("log_tag", e.toString());
    }
```

The error seems to appear in the convert response to string section. I've looked up several issues regarding similar errors to the one I received but what I read didn't seem to help much or I just don't know enough about http client coding...probably the latter. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is the PHP as well:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("/**connection*/");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM userNames WHERE user='".$_POST['name']."')";

if ($result == NULL)
{
    die();
}
else
{
    //TODO:get row to java
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
            $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
    mysql_close();
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

}
?>

The end goal of this is to convert the JSON response from the database into separate variables, the buffered reader stuff is just a middle step before the JSON conversion. Again , I just followed a tutorial so if anyone knows a different way of going about this I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried not using UTF-8 specified and let the HTTP response set the encoding?

Comment: @ns47731, I just tried that and got the same error again.

Comment: you got the solution ???